# Name of the "United States"

Tags: artículos

I always refer to The United States of America in Spanish as «**los** Estados Unidos>>.  But today I came across an article entitled *[China acusa a Estados Unidos de rehuir compromisos](http://www.absolut-china.com/china-acusa-a-estados-unidos-de-rehuir-compromisos/)*. Notice the lack of definite article in the name of the country.

Is this an acceptable or common practice? Is it perhaps because this is a headline, and headlines often omit certain words for brevity?

Answer (score 5):

My answer is only based on my experience as a user language Spanish of Chile, I don't know if there rules on the matter.

For us the name of the country is **Estados Unidos**. Users don't have awareness that we are talking about "a group of states that are united", in which case would feel the need of an article.

A map translated into Spanish label the country as "Estados Unidos", not as "Los Estados Unidos".

Then the normal mode is no article. And when we say **los Estados Unidos**  is just a matter of style, as in "*la China*" or "*el Japón*".

Comment: In English we almost always say "the United States", so maybe I just carried that habit over from my first language. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

Is an acceptable common practice. It hasn't been done for brevity in the headline.

Some names of countries **must** have the article (eg. **El** Salvador), while others can [have it or not](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12102/5481)

> (El) Afganistán; (La) Argentina; (Las) Bahamas; (La) India.

I think "Estados Unidos" only *needs* to have the "los" when we refer to the country as "**Los** Estados Unidos de América". Otherwise is kind of optional.

Interestingly, even if is "Estado**s** Unido**s**" [it is treated as a singular](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/el-alcazar-de-la-lengua-el-uso-del-articulo-en-los-nombres-de-paises-4464/)

> Estados Unidos **mantiene** su advertencia contra Irán

Unless you use the "los"

> Los Estados Unidos **mantienen** su advertencia contra Irán

I think that we favor "Estados Unidos", but is not unusual to see "Los Estados Unidos".

Comment: The Fundéu article you link has a very good explanation, in my opinion.