# ¿Cuál es el uso de 'el' en "Éste es 'el' Chile de hoy"?

Tags: gramática, artículos

He escuchado en más de una ocasión referirse a ciertos países con un artículo antes, como en *viajaré a **la** China* o *me quedo en **el** Perú*. Sin embargo nunca he escuchado que se refieran a mi país como <s>*nos veremos en **el** Chile*</s>.

Sí lo he escuchado en frases como:

> Éste es **el** Chile de hoy

pero supongo es un uso distinto del que describí al principio. Por tanto, ¿cuál es el uso del artículo *el* en este último caso?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Article usage before country names](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/672/article-usage-before-country-names)

Comment: @rsanchez pero esa pregunta/respuesta está en inglés, además que describo otro uso del artículo (el último) para el cual también me gustaría saber en que se diferencia con el primero

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Estoy de acuerdo con @rsanchez en que la primera parte de la pregunta ya está respondida en la pregunta que sugiere. El hecho de que sea en inglés no es importante (siempre puede traducirse). Dado que muestras dos dudas en tu enunciado, podrías [edit]arla para que solo haya una, la segunda.

Comment: He optado por [realizar tal edición](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/18277/revisions) para centrar la pregunta en el segundo aspecto.

Comment: @fedorqui oh, he llegado tarde a la edición, pero si, es lo que necesitaba preguntar. Muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: Fantástico :) Dudé si hacerlo o no, me alegra que estés de acuerdo y te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No solo con nombres de países y otros lugares geográficos; con nombres de personas también usamos el artículo si vamos a usar algún calificativo con ellos, tal como se especifica en el punto 5 de [este artículo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8Tu5qHMtQD63wEn6zW#5) del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas.

Por eso hablamos de *la Rusia soviética*, *el París de los bohemios* o *el Quevedo más sarcástico*, pese a que ninguno de esos nombres propios debería llevar artículo cuando se menciona sin calificativos.

Answer (score 4):

In your second question about why we say *Éste es el Chile de hoy* it is presumably because we have in mind an infinite number of hypothetical Chiles, the one of today, the one of yesterday, the one of 11 September 1973, and so on. We wish to distinguish which particular one we are talking about now. So the logic is like the difference between *un vino tinto* (any old one) and *el vino tinto* (the one we drank last night, the one the waiter recommended, ...).